# Datapower Web Service Proxy: "Match by URL" processing action does not work in response rule

Tags: soap, ibm-datapower, new-webserviceproxy

I am trying to configure a Web Service Proxy in Datapower, one that can be activated with multiple local URI's. In the WSP Policy, transactions are routed into different Processing Rules using a Match processing action that matches transactions by URL.

During the Request stage, all works as expected. During the Response stage, all transactions are routed into the default Processing Rule and not into their custom Processing Rules, ignoring the Match actions configured for the Response Processing Rules.

What may I have configured wrong? How do I get matching by URL to work in the Response stage?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is not present on the response object. Use the Probe to find out what you have on the response.
In script you can access the request variables as well so you need to match on the request variable on the response rule (server to client)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug identified by IBM
The request joining the correct request rule, but the response join in an weird response rule created which is not associated with the WSP itself
I guess this is related to huge WSDL, but not 100% sure